# Why do obviously fitting child inline-blocks overflow?

Tags: html, css

Why does the last green div overflow if I change the width of the blue div from 212px to 211px?
Where do the spaces between the green divs vome from?

The developer tools show me no margin, no padding, no border, nothing at all which could produce these gaps. Where do they come from?

**212px width --> no overflow**

[image: 212px width --> no overflow]

**211px width --> overflow**

[image: 211px width --> overflow]

```css
#test {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 211px;
}

#test>div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You turned your divs into inline elements, and inline elements are sensitive to the whitespace in your code and take up space. Remove the whitespace and the gaps go away:

```css
#test {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 211px;
}

#test>div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: an alternative it's to add `<!--` after the closing div tag and `-->` before the opening tag

Comment: @JuanCastillo Correct. Another workaround is to set `font-size:0;` on the container